# ios copy file to another apps file directory

Tags: ios, iphone

Is there anyone that got an idea of how to copy files to another apps file directory in ios? I need a service for this so I can from my app simply hit a button and what my app does is copy a file to another apps directory? will that be possible? I am ready to pay for a person that can help me with this?

Comment: Not possible on non-jailbroken devices. Apps are sandboxed.

Answer (score 1):

iOS apps are sandboxed and are not able to directly access the contents of another app's data. There are ways for apps to interact with each other, but these require user interaction and are limited to specific use cases. For more info, here are some docs from Apple on inter-app communication:

[Document Interaction Programming Topics for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010403)

[Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW2)